# Android modules vs Flavor

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I'm searching for differences between modules and flavor.

I've read those posts:

- [Android difference between module vs flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749810/android-difference-between-module-vs-flavor)
- [When to use android flavours vs separate projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345255/when-to-use-android-flavours-vs-separate-projects)

But it's still a bit blur about the differences and how to choose between one and another.

So far the only differences, I manage to get out of it is:

- Different structure

Modules can do everything that a Flavor does.

My first question is, what's the difference and what's so good about flavor that you don't use modules ?

Also, is flavor adapted for 2 applications where Application-1 and Application-2 share same code base (i.e. API, models, utils, service), but deviate from each other in terms of features and UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When to use modules:

When your project can be separated into smaller independent parts.

I've don'e this to my project, and my compile time went from 50+ seconds per iteration to less than 10 per iteration.

Because when I change code in 1 module, the others dont change and that's why the compile time is faster.

When to use flavours:

1. When you want to publish apps to different stores, and they need to have different applicationId

for example you want to publish to google play, and amazon store, and some other store that no one has heard of.

2. When you want to have part of your app available under certain build time conditions
3. When you want to whitelabel your app - basically it has the same logic but different UI, so in practice it is a completely different app, only... it's not.

Comment: Issue here is I want to use flavours for more than just this, I have 2 applications that share 80% of code, but Application-1 has feature A,B,C and Application-2 has feature A,C,E. Should I still use flavors for this ?

Comment: use modules 
the 80% code is one module, feature A is 2nd module, feature B is third module, feature C is fourth module, feature E is 5th module. You also need modules 6 and 7, one for each app.
You could forgo modules 6 and 7 for module 6 of 2 flavours, that one has different compile options.
You can do flavorCompileFeatureA . flavorCompileFeatureB flavorCompileFeature...

Comment: So there is no advantage to use flavor over module, except in module if we split everything correctly we greatly reduce the compile time. I'm not sure to understand what you mean by flavorCompileFeatureA,  flavorCompileFeatureB flavorCompileFeature.., as flavor1 will have feature A,B,C in its apk, and flavor2 will have feature A,C,E in its apk.